# Android: Letting the touch event through my transparent view (service)

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-view

I wrote a service class which creates a transparent view (LinearLayout).
If the user is holding down, some music starts to play.

This runs fine, but the problem is that if I am in the android menu or in another app, I am not able to press any buttons. (My view seems to don't let the TouchEvents pass)

I have tried a lot of things like returning false or stopping the interception, but I am still not able to press any gui controls when the service is running.

How do I correctly pass the TouchEvent back to the System?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() ==
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            Log.i(TAG, "Action :" + event.getAction() + "\t X :" + event.getRawX()
                    + "\t Y :" + event.getRawY());

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if(!mp.isPlaying())
            mp.start();
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mp.pause();
        }

        //View parent = (View) v.getParent().getParent();
        //parent.onTouchEvent(event);
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> This runs fine, but the problem is that if I am in the android menu or in another app, I am not able to press any buttons. (My view seems to don't let the TouchEvents pass)

This is by design.

> How do I correctly pass the TouchEvent back to the System?

You don't. If you have the ability to see a touch event via a system window, that touch event will not be dispatched to another app. This prevents "tapjacking" attacks.

Comment: So there is no way to dispatch the Touch Event with the official API?

Comment: @user3371692: Correct.